# MySQL - querying for a result across tables that are not directly linked

Tags: mysql, join

I want to query my database to show which musicians collaborated on a given album. The tables are arranged like so (not all songs are on an album):

**ALBUM**

albumID

**ALBUM_SONG**

albumID

songID

**SONG**

songID

**SONG_INSTRUMENT**

songID

musicianID

**MUSICIAN**

musicianID

Obviously they have other attributes too, but these are the linking attributes. I realise it is a lot of steps from musician to album. Is it possible to query the DB for "list all musicians collaborating on an album"?

Comment: sure. just chain the joins. `select musicianid from album join album->album_song, album_song->song, song->song_instrument, song_instrument->musician where albumid=foo`

Comment: I did try this but workbench comes up with an error saying it doesn't recognise the table names when i do it... could you show me in SQL?

Comment: @MichaelGibbs Depending on the operating system of the DB server, table names could be case sensitive.  Make sure you are using the correct case in the table names.

Comment: show your sql and we'll tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: `select musician.musicianForename, musician.musicianSurname, album.albumName
from musician, album
join album_song
on album_song.albumID=album.albumID
join song
on song.songID=album_song.songID
join song_instrument
on song_instrument.songID=song.songID
join musician
on musician.musicianNInumber=song_instrument.musicianNInumber
where album.albumname='what a massacre';`
As you can see, I'm trying to return musicianName rather than musicianID, same with album.

Comment: This is really close to working 

`SELECT DISTINCT mus.musicianForename, mus.musicianSurname, album.albumName
FROM album_song al_s
INNER JOIN song_instrument s_i ON al_s.songID = s_i.songID
INNER JOIN musician mus ON s_i.musicianNInumber = mus.musicianNInumber
WHERE al_s.albumID = 1;`

But that album.albumName is coming back as an unknown Column. When I take it out the rest works, but i need it to return album name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT mus.musicianforename, mus.musiciansurname, album.albumName
enter code here`FROM album_song 
INNER JOIN album ON album_song.albumID=album.albumID
INNER JOIN song_instrument s_i ON album_song.songID = s_i.songID
INNER JOIN musician mus ON s_i.musicianNInumber = mus.musicianNInumber
WHERE album.albumname = 'what a massacre';
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you just have to join through some tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT mus.musicianID
FROM album al
INNER JOIN album_song al_s ON al.albumID = al_s.albumID
INNER JOIN song_instrument s_i ON al_s.songID = s_i.songID
INNER JOIN musician mus ON s_i.musicianID = mus.musicianID
WHERE al.albumID = ?;
```

Comment: Hi, I can't make this work.. could you redo it using the following table/attribute names..?

`select musician.musicianForename, musician.musicianSurname, album.albumName
from musician, album
join album_song
on album_song.albumID=album.albumID
join song
on song.songID=album_song.songID
join song_instrument
on song_instrument.songID=song.songID
join musician
on musician.musicianNInumber=song_instrument.musicianNInumber
where album.albumname='what a massacre';`

Comment: I want to return the musician names and album name rather than IDs

Comment: This is is so close to working:

`SELECT DISTINCT mus.musicianForename, mus.musicianSurname, album.albumName
FROM album_song al_s
INNER JOIN song_instrument s_i ON al_s.songID = s_i.songID
INNER JOIN musician mus ON s_i.musicianNInumber = mus.musicianNInumber
WHERE al_s.albumID = 1;`

It all works but I can't get it to return album.albumName - when i put this in the first line it says 'unknown column 'album.albumname' in field list'

Comment: Let me re-iterate if I may - I want the user to search for album.albumName and have the results be album.albumName, musician.musicianForename and musician.musicianSurname. In other words 'which musicians collaborated on album x'. Please help... your solution got me so close! I'm desperate!

Comment: @MichaelGibbs I updated the query to include the `album` table, aliased as `al`.